# Too Many Arguments Error with Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have the below code which is triggering a stored procedure to delete a record by matching the parameter with the primary key in the table. I ran the code through debug ang everything is assigning properly, but I keep receiving an error stating there are too many arguments specified. I think it has something to do with my stored procedure because the values are being assigned properly.

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    Dim CurrentCommand As String = e.CommandName
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
    Dim ID As String = GridView1.DataKeys(CurrentRow).Value

    sqlds.DeleteParameters.Add("KeyOpType", ID)
    sqlds.Delete()


End Sub
```

Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGenInfo_DeleteMines]
(@KeyOpType int)
AS
Delete FROM GenInfo_OpType
Where KeyOpType = @KeyOpType
```

Comment: What is a `sqlds`? Why are you using `DeleteParameters.Add` instead of a command object set to stored procedure and just `Parameters.AddWithValue()` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`? You need to choose whether your VB.Net code is going to call ad hoc commands (like `DELETE`) or execute stored procedures.

Comment: Sqlds is my sqldatasource. I want to just use stored procedures. Should I just remove the sqldatasource control and create the connections in my code behind?

Comment: Yes, why would you use a data source when your goal is to call a stored procedure that deletes a single row? This is like emptying the entire fridge to throw out the bad milk.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting your delete command?  Do we know for sure that it is calling the correct procedure?  I think this is what you're trying to do .  Check this:

[SQLDataSource with GridView and CRUD](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix the problem what your having.... but

It appears you are missing the BEGIN in the stored procedure. I'm new to this, but i think that is required.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGenInfo_DeleteMines]
(@KeyOpType int)
AS
BEGIN <-----------------------------------MISSING THIS
Delete FROM GenInfo_OpType
Where KeyOpType = @KeyOpType
```

Plus, i don't see where you are calling the SP in the vb code.

EDIT: To give further examples....

My code behind on the gv Row Command would look like this... (if its coming from a button/link on the gv have to add CommandName="SomeCommandName" to the control on the gv)

```
    Protected Sub gvName_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvName.RowCommand

        Dim tGrid As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim tIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = Nothing

Select Case e.CommandName
            Case "SomeCommandName"
                CallToDelete(tGrid.DataKeys(tIndex).Value)
        End Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: BEGIN is not required (though is a best practice IMHO). And it doesn't help much if you add BEGIN but don't add END. Anyway, this is not the source of the problem.